# GAE python: Get and post request working without submitting a post request through a form

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, request, httphandler, task-queue

This is a continuation of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214677/keyerror-during-python-gae-push-task-queue-with-cron)

What follows is an abbreviated version of the original code. I tried to include the most relevant parts and left out the part of the script used by a cron job which updates the Datastore with values.

Then, in the **sendFollowUp()** handler, a second cron job queries the Datastore for these values, then uses a push task queue to send these values as parameters which are ultimately used in a REST API call to another service that sends people(entities) in the Datastore an email.

What I can't figure out is how to follow-up a get request with a post request in the same handler without submitting a post request through a form. This needs to happen within the sendFollowUp handler. Most of the examples I have found include submitting a form. However, I don't want to do that. I just want it to work automatically with the cron job and task queue.

```
import webapp2
import datetime
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
import jinja2
import os

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

class emailJobs(db.Model):
    """ Models an a list of email jobs for each user """
    triggerid = db.StringProperty()  #Trig id
    recipientid_po = db.StringProperty() # id
    recipientlang = db.StringProperty()  #Language
    fu_email_sent = db.DateTimeProperty() 
    fuperiod = db.IntegerProperty() # (0 - 13)
    fu1 = db.DateTimeProperty() 
    fu2 = db.DateTimeProperty()

    @classmethod
    def update_fusent(cls, key_name, senddate):
        """ Class method that updates fu messages sent in the GAE Datastore """
        emailsjobs = cls.get_by_key_name(key_name)
        if emailsjobs is None:
            emailsjobs = cls(key_name=key_name)
        emailsjobs.fu_email_sent = senddate
        emailsjobs.put()

def timeStampFM(now):
    d = now.date()
    year = d.year
    month = d.month
    day = d.day
    t = now.time()
    hour = t.hour
    minute = t.minute + 5
    second = t.second
    today_datetime = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
    return today_datetime


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """ Main admin login page """
    def get(self):
        if users.get_current_user():
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Logout'
            urla = '/'
            url_admin = ""
            if users.is_current_user_admin():
                url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
                urla = "_ah/admin/"
                url_admin = 'Go to admin pages'
                url_linktext = 'Logout'

        else:
            url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Login'

        template_values = {
            'url': url,
            'url_linktext': url_linktext,
            'url_admin': url_admin,
            'urla': urla,
            }

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))


class sendFollowUp(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """ Queries Datastore for fu dates that match today's date, then adds them to a task queue """
    def get(self):

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        now_dt = now.date() #today's date to compare with fu dates

        q = emailJobs.all()
        q.filter('fuperiod >', 0)
        q.filter('fuperiod <', 99)

        for part in q:
            guid = str(part.recipientid_po)
            lang = str(part.recipientlang)
            trigid = str(part.triggerid)

            if part.fuperiod == 1:
                fu1rawdt = part.fu1
                fu1dt = fu1rawdt.date()
                if fu1dt == now_dt:
                    follow_up = '1'

            if part.fuperiod == 2: # the values go up to 12 in the original code
                fu2rawdt = part.fu2
                fu2dt = fu2rawdt.date()
                if fu2dt == now_dt:
                    follow_up = '2'

        if follow_up != None:
            taskqueue.add(queue_name='emailworker', url='/emailworker', params={'guid': guid,
                                                                            'fu': follow_up,
                                                                            'lang': lang,
                                                                            'trigid': trigid,
                                                                            })
        self.redirect('/emailworker')


class pushQueue(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """ Sends fu emails, updates the Datastore with datetime sent """

    def store_emails(self, trigid, senddate):
        db.run_in_transaction(emailJobs.update_fusent, trigid, senddate)

    def get(self):
        fu_messages = {'1': 'MS_x01', 
                       '2': 'MS_x02',
                       # the values go up to 12 in the original code
                       }
        langs = {'EN': 'English subject',
                 'ES': 'Spanish subject',
                 }

        fu = str(self.request.get('fu'))
        messageid = fu_messages[fu]

        lang = str(self.request.get('lang'))
        subject = langs[lang]

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        senddate = timeStampFM(now)

        guid = str(self.request.get('guid'))
        trigid = str(self.request.get('trigid'))

        data = {}
        data['Subject'] = subject
        data['MessageID'] = messageid
        data['SendDate'] = senddate
        data['RecipientID'] = guid
        # Here I do something with data = {}

        self.store_emails(trigid, senddate)

    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                       ('/cron/sendfu', sendFollowUp),
                       ('/emailworker', pushQueue)],
                       debug=True)
```

Comment: I do not understand why you like to use a kind of internal post. Why not call a method or function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I really understand your question, but can't you just create a POST request with the `requests` module?

[Post Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

```
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
```

Also for easy task use have you seen the deferred library?

> The deferred library lets you bypass all the work of setting up dedicated task handlers and serializing and deserializing your parameters by exposing a simple function, deferred.defer(). To call a function later, simply pass the function and its arguments to deferred.defer

[Link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred)

Comment: Hi. Thanks! I think deferred sounds like the way to go but I don't quite understand how to integrate it with my current code.